# Can't find long-duration nature videos in 4K

Tags: video

I'd like to purchase long-duration nature videos (30mn or even 1hr), in order to use them for a personal musical project, and then share on YouTube.
So, basically I also need to buy a license for that.

Until now, the thing is that I only found "short" 4K nature videos (a couple of seconds long, several minutes at most). I can't believe long-duration videos are not available, for sale or even for free, I just didn't find relevant websites.

Can anybody help?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Stock videos are typically quite short. They cannot be long because they wouldn't sell well as the probability that you find a person, who needs exactly this video, plummets dramatically for longer videos. That's why you can't find anything. I can't rule out that there's some corner of the web where you can find such videos, but long stock videos are definitely rare.

I see a couple of options:

- hire somebody to shoot the custom video for you, but this will be expensive
- get a couple of clips and assemble them to make a longer video. You could use cross-dissolve transitions to gradually go from one clip to the next. Pretty much every video editor software can do this or ask somebody to do it for you.
- create a slideshow video from a number of photographs
- loop a short clip
- evaluate if video is really required for your project. The simple fact that you're trying to find long videos on the web feels odd to me. When I come across a long music clip with no interesting video, like 1 hour of waves rolling onto the beach, I stop looking at it after a minute. The video serves no purpose for me.

I can't recommend any option in particular, nor do I know if they could wok for you, because I don't know the details of your project.